# Extracting charts from Socrata as you would a dataset

Tags: r, socrata

I need some help with extracting charts as you would a dataset and though the visualizations appear to be saved in the catalog as assets, I have not been able to find a way to pull the visualization out. I need to do this for at least 100 charts (all with different formatting) and it's looking like the only way I will be able to do this is to pull the dataset for each chart, recreate the chart in R and hopefully export it into excel (if that's even a thing).

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The charts aren't machine readable. You'd need to create the chart in a separate program (R, Excel, etc.)

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. This is going to be a bear!